# Mathematica "forgetting" the Latin Modern Roman font is installed

Tags: output-formatting, labeling, windows, fonts

I have installed Latin Modern Roman fonts (on Windows), and in the past I was always able to use them with `FontFamily` when making plots, etc. Recently, however, I have encountered a problem where Mathematica does not recognize that these fonts are installed, and they don't appear in `$FontFamilies`. If I reinstall the fonts (in which case Windows tells me the font is already installed) while Mathematica is running, then it will recognize them until I close it and reopen it, after which it "forgets" again. Is this a known issue and is there any way to deal with it?

Version: Mathematica 13.1

Comment: Please specify the version when you use the [tag:bugs] tag

Comment: @polfosol included

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior.  They are always present in `$FontFamilies`.

Comment: It is strongly recommended **not** to add this tag until it is verified/reproduced by other users. I failed to reproduce this issue as well.

Comment: Are these fonts also available in other applications?  Like the new Notepad or Word?  You can also see more details of the fonts presented by Windows by evaluating ``FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`FontCatalog[]``.